# Intersecting shapes on a flat surface

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the maximum number of enclosed regions that you can create by drawing two circles and two triangles on a flat surface? Try answering with mathematical arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have any mathematical arguments, but the best I have managed is 33 regions.

> [image]

Comment: Congratulations Daniel Mathias! You got it right!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the great puzzle!!

The highest I've gotten so far is:

33 regions. Below is a visual representation:

> [image: 33]

I've also gotten:

32 regions:

> [image: Visual representation for 32 regions]

30 regions:

> [image: 30 regions representation]

29 Regions:

> [image: 29 regions]

Comment: Ankit, you are very close to the answer.

Comment: I count only 33 regions where you claim 40...

Comment: Ok I'll add something to count it @DanielMathias

Comment: Apparently I did miscount... it is 39. The counting is now included in the picture @DanielMathias

Comment: Your groups of 10 contain only 8 regions each.

Comment: LOL wow I can't count you are correct sorry. I am fixing that. @DanielMathias

Comment: Bravo! I didn’t figure out that there were many answers.